# Need help with Custom Post Types and Taxonomies

Tags: custom-post-types, functions, register-taxonomy

I'm trying to get my head around CPT and Taxonomies. I've created a section on my WP site called Work and so I've got this in my functions.php file:

```
add_action('init', 'work_register');

function work_register() {

$labels = array(
    'name' => _x('Work', 'post type general name'),
    'singular_name' => _x('Work Item', 'post type singular name'),
    'add_new' => _x('Add New Work Item', 'portfolio item'),
    'add_new_item' => __('Add New Work Item'),
    'edit_item' => __('Edit Work Item'),
    'new_item' => __('New Work Item'),
    'view_item' => __('View Work Item'),
    'search_items' => __('Search Work'),
    'not_found' =>  __('Nothing found'),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __('Nothing found in Trash'),
    'parent_item_colon' => ''
);

$args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'public' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'menu_position' => null,
    'supports' => array('title','editor','thumbnail'),
    'taxonomies' => array('category', 'post_tag') // this is IMPORTANT
  ); 

register_post_type('work' , $args );
}

register_taxonomy("work-categories", array("work"), array("hierarchical" => true, "label" => "Work Categories", "singular_label" => "Work Category", "rewrite" => true));
```

And I think I've got all of that right as I've got a section in my admin where I can add Work items. I wasn't sure whether to include this line:

```
'taxonomies' => array('category', 'post_tag') // this is IMPORTANT
```

because I want to create a new taxonomy called 'work categories' hence registering this at the end of my code using

```
register_taxonomy("work-categories", array("work"), array("hierarchical" => true, "label" => "Work Categories", "singular_label" => "Work Category", "rewrite" => true));
```

The admin screen displays a column for Categories and Tags, but not one for Work Categories - How do I ditch the columns for Categories and Tags and add a column for Work Categories??? What else do I need to add to my functions.php file to do this??

Also I want to know how I will be able to lists my Work Categories within my sidebar on my index-work.php and single-work.php pages.

-----EDIT-----

I've added the following code to my index-work.php and single-work.php pages just before calling the sidebar:

```
<h1>Categories</h1>
<?php
$taxonomy = 'work-categories';
$queried_term = get_query_var($taxonomy);
$terms = get_terms($taxonomy, 'slug='.$queried_term);
if ($terms) {
echo '<ul>';
foreach($terms as $term) {
echo '<li><a href="'.get_term_link($term, $taxonomy).'">'.$term->name.'</a></li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
}
?>
```

And this now outputs my Work Categories, but the links for these are /work-categories/artists/ for example which is fine, but they use the archive.php page - how can I get them to link to a page I've created? I've tried archive-artists.php but this isn't picked up. I don't want to use the blog archive.php page to display my work categories. Any ideas???

-----END EDIT-----

Thanks

E

Comment: You should try to frame your questions on this site as actual questions, rather than a statement like this one. The process of converting the title to a question will help you define your issue into something more general as well as making it more interesting to people looking to write answers.

Answer (score 1):

The page for 'work categories' appears as a sub-menu page of 'Work' CPT, after you've registered it correctly. These are very good posts to get started with CPTs: [Thinkvitamin](http://thinkvitamin.com/code/create-your-first-wordpress-custom-post-type/) and [Justin Tadlock](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2010/04/29/custom-post-types-in-wordpress). I always refer these when stuck with CPTs.

Comment: I've used both those site links to get where I am now but neither help to answer my query. I tried customising the code from ThinkVitamin to show columns in my admin panel for my Work Categories but it doesn't work.

Comment: Ohh, sorry, I had scrolled a bit down so couldn't see it!